# Customize default Alert component - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an Alert to show the user the payment value, like this:

```
Alert.alert('Payment Value', 'The payment value is $' + paymentValue);
```

I've been searching but can't find a way to make the value text bold or increase the font size, is it possible to do that? Or I'll have to create a custom alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs, https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert#options-android, it doesn't seem like there is a way to customize the font size or style. You'll most likely have to create a custom component using a `Modal`. If you don't want to go that far, there is the option of changing an Alert's `Type` or `Style`.